# how to make table page width and column to automatically adjust to fit text

Tags: tables

I want table total size = page width and each column to automatically adjust so no new line. My algorithm and result and how i want it to be are all below

[image: latex]

[image]

```
\chapter*{Appendix B: Camera Calibration Data}

\begin{tabu} to \textwidth { | X[c] | X[c] | X[c] | X[c] | X[c] | X[c] | X[c] |}
  \hline
Giallo 1 &  77.261978 & 9.3193226 & 240  &  840 &   1405 &  165\\
  \hline
Giallo 2 &  77.568573 & 34.337677 & 425  &  395 &   1495 &  400\\
  \hline
Giallo 3 &  77.648048 & 57.3634   & 525  &  180 &   1650 &  775\\
  \hline
Giallo 4 &  97.427101 & 56.906445 & 1375 &  180 &   290  &  765\\
  \hline
Giallo 5 &  96.904655 & 9.5490179 & 1605 &  795 &   580  &  170\\
\hline
  \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{}\\
 \hline
Fisso 6 &   104.86995 & 0.1017158 & -    &  -   &   295  &  105\\
  \hline
Fisso 7 &   104.90186 & 13.779555 & -    &  -   &   210  &  205\\
  \hline
Fisso 8 &   88.314507 & 15.439806 & 1025 &  705 &   930  &  205\\
  \hline
Fisso 9 &   88.519508 & 54.162239 & 995  &  205 &   905  &  705\\
  \hline
Fisso 10 &  104.91088 & 54.122761 & 1725 &  200 &   -    &  -\\
  \hline
Fisso 11 &  104.91105 & 67.927704 & 1645 &  100 &   -    &  -\\
  \hline
Fisso 12 &  104.88148 & 43.205231 & 1800 &  300 &   -    &  -\\
  \hline
Fisso 13 &  99.531624 & 43.12846  & 1535 &  300 & 275    &  525\\
  \hline
Fisso 14 &  99.547058 & 24.85062  & 1650 &  520 & 400    &  300\\
  \hline
Fisso 15 &  104.88358 & 24.879362 & -    &  -   & 130    &  300\\
  \hline
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{}\\
 \hline
Bianco 16 & 85.133896 & 3.8741865 & 780  & 925  & 1070  &   130\\
  \hline
Bianco 17 & 72.73455  & 3.8047862 & -    & -    & 1570  &   130\\
  \hline
Bianco 18 & 72.379257 & 62.353729 & 320  &  140 &   -   &   -\\
  \hline
Bianco 19 & 85.527481 & 62.000118 & 865  & 145  & 1110  &   870\\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{}\\
 \hline
Fisso 20  & 93.989212 & 34.106133 & 1290 &  400 & 635   &   400\\
  \hline
\end{tabu}
```

Comment: If you change "`Bianco 16`" to "`Bianco~16`" and the same for others, it will not be split over two lines.

Comment: To get more room, round your numbers according to the precision of your measurement. As the number of decimal places varies from 4 to 6, it seems this did not yet happen.

Comment: I would prefer not to round my numbers but I still used it anyway :) Simple solution. And the solution to use ~ is really cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course I cannot judge the precision of your measurement, but I guess that it is worse than `10^{-6}` [whatever units your numbers are in]. So you should anyway round the figures to a meaningful value. In return you will have enough room for the first row.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}    
\chapter*{Appendix B: Camera Calibration Data}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|*{2}{S[table-format=3.4,round-mode=places,round-precision=4]|}*{4}{S[table-format=4.0]|}}
    \hline
    Giallo 1 &  77.261978 & 9.3193226 & 240  &  840 &   1405 &  165\\\hline
    Giallo 2 &  77.568573 & 34.337677 & 425  &  395 &   1495 &  400\\\hline
    Giallo 3 &  77.648048 & 57.3634   & 525  &  180 &   1650 &  775\\\hline
    Giallo 4 &  97.427101 & 56.906445 & 1375 &  180 &   290  &  765\\\hline
    Giallo 5 &  96.904655 & 9.5490179 & 1605 &  795 &   580  &  170\\\hline
    Fisso 6 &   104.86995 & 0.1017158 & {-}    &  {-}   &   295  &  105\\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a complete example. Just increase the width pf the first three columns a bit:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Appendix B: Camera Calibration Data}

\begin{tabu} to \textwidth { | X[1.5, c] | X[1.5, c]| X[1.5, c] | X[c] | X[c] | X[c] | X[c] |}
  \hline
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Camera 1}  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Camera 2} \\ 
\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{World Coordinates} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Image Coordinates}  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Image Coordinates} \\ 
\hline
Giallo 1 &  77.261978 & 9.3193226 & 240  &  840 &   1405 &  165\\
  \hline
Giallo 2 &  77.568573 & 34.337677 & 425  &  395 &   1495 &  400\\
  \hline
Giallo 3 &  77.648048 & 57.3634   & 525  &  180 &   1650 &  775\\
  \hline
Giallo 4 &  97.427101 & 56.906445 & 1375 &  180 &   290  &  765\\
  \hline
Giallo 5 &  96.904655 & 9.5490179 & 1605 &  795 &   580  &  170\\
\hline
  \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{}\\
 \hline
Fisso 6 &   104.86995 & 0.1017158 & -    &  -   &   295  &  105\\
  \hline
Fisso 7 &   104.90186 & 13.779555 & -    &  -   &   210  &  205\\
  \hline
Fisso 8 &   88.314507 & 15.439806 & 1025 &  705 &   930  &  205\\
  \hline
Fisso 9 &   88.519508 & 54.162239 & 995  &  205 &   905  &  705\\
  \hline
Fisso 10 &  104.91088 & 54.122761 & 1725 &  200 &   -    &  -\\
  \hline
Fisso 11 &  104.91105 & 67.927704 & 1645 &  100 &   -    &  -\\
  \hline
Fisso 12 &  104.88148 & 43.205231 & 1800 &  300 &   -    &  -\\
  \hline
Fisso 13 &  99.531624 & 43.12846  & 1535 &  300 & 275    &  525\\
  \hline
Fisso 14 &  99.547058 & 24.85062  & 1650 &  520 & 400    &  300\\
  \hline
Fisso 15 &  104.88358 & 24.879362 & -    &  -   & 130    &  300\\
  \hline
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{}\\
 \hline
Bianco 16 & 85.133896 & 3.8741865 & 780  & 925  & 1070  &   130\\
  \hline
Bianco 17 & 72.73455  & 3.8047862 & -    & -    & 1570  &   130\\
  \hline
Bianco 18 & 72.379257 & 62.353729 & 320  &  140 &   -   &   -\\
  \hline
Bianco 19 & 85.527481 & 62.000118 & 865  & 145  & 1110  &   870\\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{}\\
 \hline
Fisso 20  & 93.989212 & 34.106133 & 1290 &  400 & 635   &   400\\
  \hline
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your columns do contain diffenrent amounts of numbers. So you should not use the same width for any column. Just stretch the first one, if you really want to get the maximum width here:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}    
\chapter*{Appendix B: Camera Calibration Data}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{%
        X
        S[table-format=3.6]
        S[table-format=2.7]
        S[table-format=4.0]
        S[table-format=3.0]
        S[table-format=4.0]
        S[table-format=3.0]
    }
    \toprule
    Giallo 1 &  77.261978 & 9.3193226 & 240  &  840 &   1405 &  165\\
    Giallo 2 &  77.568573 & 34.337677 & 425  &  395 &   1495 &  400\\
    Giallo 3 &  77.648048 & 57.3634   & 525  &  180 &   1650 &  775\\
    Giallo 4 &  97.427101 & 56.906445 & 1375 &  180 &   290  &  765\\
    Giallo 5 &  96.904655 & 9.5490179 & 1605 &  795 &   580  &  170\\
    \addlinespace
    Fisso 6 &   104.86995 & 0.1017158 & {-}    &  {-}   &   295  &  105\\
    Fisso 7 &   104.90186 & 13.779555 & {-}    &  {-}   &   210  &  205\\
    Fisso 8 &   88.314507 & 15.439806 & 1025 &  705 &   930  &  205\\
    Fisso 9 &   88.519508 & 54.162239 & 995  &  205 &   905  &  705\\
    Fisso 10 &  104.91088 & 54.122761 & 1725 &  200 &   {-}    &  {-}\\
    Fisso 11 &  104.91105 & 67.927704 & 1645 &  100 &   {-}    &  {-}\\
    Fisso 12 &  104.88148 & 43.205231 & 1800 &  300 &   {-}    &  {-}\\
    Fisso 13 &  99.531624 & 43.12846  & 1535 &  300 & 275    &  525\\
    Fisso 14 &  99.547058 & 24.85062  & 1650 &  520 & 400    &  300\\
    Fisso 15 &  104.88358 & 24.879362 & {-}    &  {-}   & 130    &  300\\
    \addlinespace
    Bianco~16 & 85.133896 & 3.8741865 & 780  & 925  & 1070  &   130\\
    Bianco~17 & 72.73455  & 3.8047862 & {-}    & {-}    & 1570  &   130\\
    Bianco~18 & 72.379257 & 62.353729 & 320  &  140 &   {-}   &   {-}\\
    Bianco~19 & 85.527481 & 62.000118 & 865  & 145  & 1110  &   870\\
    \addlinespace
    Fisso 20  & 93.989212 & 34.106133 & 1290 &  400 & 635   &   400\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```